# How can I avoid array or single error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When `@notification_users` contains more than 2 arrays, this won't be error.
However, it returns this error `undefined method`+' for nil:NilClass`when`@notification_users.count.to_s` = 1

How can I avoid error even when it has only one record(Not array)?

```
@notification_users.each do |user|
    @users_emails += [user.email]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is actually stating that `@users_emails` is nil when you try to append/push an element into that object.

You can initialize `@users_emails` as an empty array and then push elements into your array.

```
@users_emails = []
@notification_users.each do |user|
  @users_emails << user.email
end
```

This ensures that `@users_emails` will always be an array.

Comment: If the OP initializes `@users_emails = []` as you indicated, then the `@users_emails += [user.email]` would also work. +1 for catching the root cause.

Comment: @MKK Np, glad I was able to help :)